# How to feature test for BigInt support?

Tags: javascript, language-features, arbitrary-precision, ecma262

I'm not familiar with modern JS and tooling to even try something.

References:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint

Comment: [MDN BigInt#browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#browser_compatibility) what's your target audience/device that you think it might not be available?

Comment: @Thomas 1. I use really old browsers sometimes. 2. ActionScript won't get updates any time soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invoke `BigInt` and catch a possible exception:

```
let BigIntSupported = true

try {
    BigInt(1)
} catch (e) {
    BigIntSupported = false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if('BigInt' in window)` (or `if(window.BigInt)`) should suffice.

Comment: I can't find any references yet... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#search_for_the_global_across_environments

Answer (score 0):

`globalThis.BigInt === BigInt` without any polyfill.

```js
console.log(globalThis.BigInt === BigInt);
```

I did just 2 tests with Firefox 119.1.1 and it seems to work... Second test had intentional typo and failed as expected.

References:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global

I can't edit my older answer for some reason...

Answer (score -1):

`globalThis.BigInt === BigInt`

`core-js`'s polyfill requires Chrome 71 or Firefox 65.

References:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global

http://zloirock.github.io/core-js/compat/

Comment: This won't do what you want – you'll get either a NameError if `Foo` is not defined, or if `Foo` is `undefined`, you'll get `true` when they're both undefined.

Comment: @AKX I did just 2 tests with Firefox 119.1.1 and it seems to work... Second test had intentional typo and failed as expected.